# Where does the term "bucket" in cloud storage come from?

Tags: etymology, computing

In Amazon S3, Google Cloud storage, etc., they refer to containers that hold data as [buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#buckets).

I was curious where this originated from. The closest I could find was maybe [bit bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_bucket) maybe referring to the fact you can store anything in it. Any other insights as to the origin would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It appears the the term  [bucket](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_(computing)#) is just a generally accepted metaphor:

> In computing, the term bucket can have several meanings. It is used both as a live metaphor, and as a generally accepted technical term in some specialised areas. A bucket is most commonly a type of data buffer or a type of document in which data is divided into regions.

***Bit bucket:***

> This is a humorous but common phrase. Something goes into the bit bucket when it is deleted, generally irreversibly and quite often wrongly, such as files or emails that just disappear.
>
> It has been commonly suggested  that this usage dates from the days when punched cards and/or punched tape were common. Card and paper-tape punches each had a receptacle for the chips punched from the cards or tape to create the holes (rectangular in a card, round in a paper tape), which often looked like a bucket and was known by this name. By analogy it was jokingly suggested  that the CPU, which in those days was an equipment rack of similar size to a large peripheral unit, contained a similar receptacle for lost data.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: Thanks for the answer (although I posted the same link in my answer). I am starting to suspect `bucket` originated from hashing and spread from there. But you are right that it is just a metaphor for a container to hold data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a limb here, but I am starting to suspect that the term "bucket" originated with [Hans Peter Luhn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Peter_Luhn).
Excerpt from [here](https://medium.com/@dieswaytoofast/the-invention-of-the-hashing-algorithm-600933d7f845):

> In early 1953, Luhn had written an internal IBM memo in which he
> suggested putting information into “buckets” in order to speed up a
> search. Let’s say you wanted to look up a telephone number in a
> database and find out whom it belonged to. Given the 10-digit number
> 314–159–2652, a computer could simply search through the list one
> number at a time until it found the relevant entry. In a database of
> millions of numbers, though, this could take a while.

Also from [here](https://www.encyclopedia.com/science-and-technology/computers-and-electrical-engineering/computers-and-computing/bucket):

> A subdivision of a data file, serving as the unit within which records
> are located. Buckets are specially used in connection with hashing
> techniques, and with indexing techniques (see index) where index
> entries point to groups of records. In these circumstances, hashing or
> indexing will yield the address of the start of the bucket; the
> location for storage or retrieval within the bucket will then be found
> by searching.

It makes sense to me that to lookup a bucket, some type of hashing/indexing technique is used, so that is why they are called `buckets` for cloud storage as well.